# Distinct after query as result

Tags: sql

Distinct values

Hi, I have table ITEM_PRICE, I'd like to get distinct item_id and then use WHERE price = 10

For now I have query

```
Select distinct item_id from item where price = 10
```

In result I get DISTINCT item_id where price = 10

I'd like to have first result of Distinct and then apply my Where. Because I need ITEM_ID which is only visible one time in DB and after find item with specific price.

Comment: can you pls add your DB version, type and expected result ?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: The results would be the same no matter if you apply the Distinct first then Where or the other way arround.   Please describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You may want to look into subqueries:   Select item_id from item where price=10 and item_id in (select distinct item_id from ....  )

Answer (score 1):

> Because I need ITEM_ID which is only visible one time in DB and after find item with specific price.

This sounds like you want `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  The following returns items that appear exactly once with a price of `10`:

```
select item_id
from item 
group by item_id
having count(*) = 1 and min(price) = 10;
```

If you wanted items that have only one price but could have multiple rows (with that price), you could tweak this to:

```
select item_id
from item 
group by item_id
having max(price) = min(price) and min(price) = 10
```